# postgresql - how to display all values inside the 'in' operator?

Tags: postgresql

My query is like this:

```
select lvl_desc, fct.patient_age_group as Age_group,fct.client_id,
fct.geog_algn_id,USC_3_CODE, PAYMENT_TYPE ,patient_gender_desc,
SUM(nvl(Tot_Mkt,0)) as Tot_Mkt
FROM MY_FACT_TABLE fct
     inner join MY_DIM_TABLE geo on fct.client_id = geo.client_id 
                           and fct.geog_algn_id = geo.geog_algn_id 
                           and fct.lvl_desc = geo.geog_lvl_15_desc
WHERE fct.client_id = 10000 
and fct.geog_algn_id = 10000 
and geog_lvl_03_desc = 'BC'
and USC_3_CODE = 31000
AND PAYMENT_TYPE = 'BLA2'
AND patient_gender_desc = 'MALE'
AND patient_age_group in ('19-25','3-5', '30-34', '35-39')
and lvl_desc = 'BLA1'
GROUP BY fct.client_id,fct.geog_algn_id,lvl_desc,USC_3_CODE, PAYMENT_TYPE ,patient_gender_desc, patient_age_group
order by lvl_desc,age_group;
```

My query returns data for age group 30-34 and 35-39 because the fact table has data. I want to return zero(0) for the missing age groups 3-5 and 19-25.
How can I do this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use a LEFT JOIN with COALESCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [VALUES](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-values.html) to supply a few set of data, or some [set-returning function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) (like `generate_series()`) when you need a generated range of data (and use left joins, to get `NULL` where there is no data):

```
select lvl_desc, fct.patient_age_group as Age_group,fct.client_id,
       fct.geog_algn_id,USC_3_CODE, PAYMENT_TYPE ,patient_gender_desc,
       SUM(nvl(Tot_Mkt,0)) as Tot_Mkt
FROM (VALUES ('19-25', '3-5', '30-34', '35-39')) v(patient_age_group)
left join MY_FACT_TABLE fct on fct.patient_age_group = v.patient_age_group
left join MY_DIM_TABLE geo on fct.client_id = geo.client_id 
                          and fct.geog_algn_id = geo.geog_algn_id 
                          and fct.lvl_desc = geo.geog_lvl_15_desc
WHERE fct IS NULL OR (
    fct.client_id = 10000 
    and fct.geog_algn_id = 10000 
    and geog_lvl_03_desc = 'BC'
    and USC_3_CODE = 31000
    AND PAYMENT_TYPE = 'BLA2'
    AND patient_gender_desc = 'MALE'
    and lvl_desc = 'BLA1'
)
GROUP BY fct.client_id,fct.geog_algn_id,lvl_desc,USC_3_CODE,
         PAYMENT_TYPE ,patient_gender_desc, patient_age_group
order by lvl_desc,age_group;
```

Comment: what is the v in 'v(patient_age_group)' ?

Comment: `v(patient_age_group)` is the alias for the `VALUES` expression (`v` is the table alias, `patient_age_group` is the column alias)